# Get "Could not write metadata for..." error at Jaspersoft Studio during publishing report

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am getting the following exception while trying to publish report changes to the *JasperReport Server* using *Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1*:

[image]

A few things I noticed that sometimes seem to lead to a successful publishing are

- keeping the app idle for a few minutes
- renaming / deleting the "2f" folder including properties.index (this
  works only once)
- setting the apps priority to high in task manager (this is the best
  solution so far but it doesn't solve the problem completely)

I also tried to change the workspace and reinstall Jaspersoft Studio several times (didn't help at all).

Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Are you using Studio or a plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: Using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1

Comment: Have you tried starting Jaspersoft Studio with the "-clean" argument?

Comment: I did try your ("-clean" argument) solution but still getting the exception.